# Is there a way in D7 that allows for multiple links in an image in a slider?

Tags: 7, javascript

Is there a way in Drupal 7 that allows for multiple links in an image in a slider?

Comment: @NoSssweat (about your comment I saw here a few secs ago): ***Really***??? What about **[these (495 ...) questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3Amodule+which+-how+closed%3Ano)** ?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens where did my comment go? apparently we cant use the M word in comments? :O

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens 495 results... maybe the mods have been lying to me?

Comment: Hm, looks like it's time for a meta.drupal.SE question (maybe even 2 or 3) ... I'm getting confused about all sorts of variations of questions for which an answer could be like "**sure there is a (or multiple...) module(s) for it**" (which I hope is still OK as an **answer** " ...). BUT: "*When I have time some day*" I might post such meta question(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content **(not
> just images)** that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is
> heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View
> you create

Then add a custom field to your view and put the links there.